# CSS3 hover on nested divs

Tags: css, hover, nested

I have mutlilevel nested divs. Each div has a span in it.

```
<div>
    <span>AA</span>
    <div>
        <span>BB</span>
        <div>
            <span>CC</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I hover a div, the spans css should get another background. This works pretty well, as long as i hover the most outer div, containting the AA span.
But the problem is, if i hover the middle div, containing the BB span, the outer div hovers as well. If i hover the CC span div all three spans get the background.

What I want is, that only the one div which the mouse points at is hovered.
I look preferably for a CSS solution, but jQUery would be great as well.

Here is a simplified jsfiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/FufRg/

Comment: Is it an option to use 3 seperate divs instead of nested divs? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MJqzM/)

Answer (score 1):

In jquery this is easy. just stop propagation.
[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FufRg/8/)

```
$("div").on("mouseover",function(e){
    $(this).children("span").css("background","#AAA");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("div").on("mouseout",function(){
    $(this).children("span").css("background","");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Think in this way. If you enter a house, than into a room, than into the bed you are still in the house-> in the room -> in the bed. You cant say you are only in the bed, or only in the room. I think you get my point. If you hover over the `CC` `div` the `hover` will trigger on all the `div`s because you are already over the `AA` `div` and the `bb` `div`. The best solution is to use separate `div`s, not nested. Like  Aquillo said.

Answer (score 0):

I have create an example and it works for me. I have added jQuery and jQuery UI for background animation:

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
  <span>AA</span>
   <div class="b">
    <span>BB</span>
     <div class="c">
        <span>CC</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

    .a{width: 400px;
         height: 400px;
         background: #000;}

    .b{width: 300px;
         height: 300px;
         background: #ddd;}

    .c{width: 200px;
         height: 200px;
         background: #efefee;}

</style>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$('.a').hover(function(){

    $(this).find('*').animate({'backgroundColor': 'red'},400);

});

$('.b').hover(function(){

    $(this).find('*').animate({'backgroundColor': 'blue'},400);

});

$('.c').hover(function(){

    $(this).find('*').animate({'backgroundColor': 'yellow'},400);

});

});
</script>
```